# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n\log n}{e^n}?$

Tags: real-analysis

How to test the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n\log n}{e^n}?$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual, I love D'Alemberts ratio test:

$$a_n:=\frac{n\log n}{e^n}\Longrightarrow \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+1)\log(n+1)}{e^{n+1}}\frac{e^n}{n\log n}=$$
$$=\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\frac{1}{e}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{1}{e}<1$$

and thus the series converges.

Comment: Does $\dfrac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\to 1?$ How can it be proved?

Comment: For example with L'Hospital, say: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(x+1)}{\log x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x+1}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x+1}=1$$

Comment: Or by the squeeze theorem, too, using monotony of $\log n\,$: $$1=\frac{\log n}{\log n}\le\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\le\frac{\log 2n}{\log n}=\frac{\log 2}{\log n}+\frac{\log n}{\log n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$$

Answer (score 2):

You can easily show that
$$
\frac{n\log n}{e^n}=O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
$$
All you have to do is check that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}n^2 \cdot\frac{n\log n}{e^n}=0.
$$

Then conclude the series converges (absolutely, of course) by comparison with the Riemann series $\sum_{n\geq 1}  \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: you confused me with your edit, maybe cause i don't like the $=\mathcal{O}()$ notation, for a freshan wouldn't it be easiert to show $n \log(n) <n^2$ and $e^n > n^4$ ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Yes, sure. But in many instances (not here, I agree) the big O notation is very useful and it makes it a bummer to avoid it. So the sooner you encounter it, the better, imo.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I've indeed noticed the general preference here to manipulate inequalities when solving this kind of questions. I do it sometimes. But I find it artificial. So I don't always do it. Because I am not sure this is the best way to prepare the freshman to treat more delicate cases where easy inequalities don't suffice. By the way $e^n\geq n^4/4!$ is easy, $e^n\geq n^4$ is less easy.

Comment: +1 for the elegant approach. I think this question has got enough points, form yours to Don's.

Comment: @BabakS. Thanks, Babak.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis By the way, aren't you german like Landau? You should promote your heritage!

Comment: @julien j'aime ton carré rouge! :)

Comment: @Bruno Ah! Someone understood the reference! This is indeed more or less a private joke.

Answer (score 1):

Another Hint:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{2}\times\frac{n\log(n)}{\exp(n)}=0<\infty$$ so it converges.

Comment: Hi Babak! You want $n^2$, not $n^1$, I think.

Comment: @julien: Hi!. Yes, it could be, but I evaluated with $n^{1}$ and gets the answer. Thanks. Your suggestion is good. I'll consider it.

Comment: Good work! ;-) +

Answer (score 0):

First note that $e^n > n^4$ for $n$ large enough. That is, first prove that there is a $K$ such that $e^n > n^4$ for all $n\geq K$.

Then you have for $n\geq K$ also that $\log(n) < n$ and so
$$
\frac{n\log(n)}{e^n} < \frac{n\log(n)}{n^4} < \frac{n^2}{n^4} = \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Hence you can compare the sequence to $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test is probably the best tool to use in this case (and in many other examples), but you may also use the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Let $f(x)=x\log x/e^x$. Clearly $f(x)$ is positive for all $x > 1$. Moreover $f(x)$ is decreasing at least on $[e,\infty)$. Indeed,
$$f'(x) = \frac{1+(1-x)\log(x)}{e^x}$$
so if $x\geq e$, then the numerator of $f'(x)$ is less than $1+(1-e)<0$. Hence $f'(x)<0$ for $x\geq e$, and $f$ is decreasing. Hence, we may apply the integral test on the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$.

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=3}^\infty f(n)$ converges and this series, by the integral test, converges if and only if $\int_3^\infty f(x)dx$ converges. Now:

$$\int_3^\infty f(x) dx = \lim_{N\to \infty} \int_3^N \frac{x\log x}{e^x} dx \leq \lim_{N\to \infty} \int_3^N \frac{x^2}{e^x} dx = \lim_{N\to\infty} [-e^{-x}(x^2+2x+2)]_3^N$$
$$ = \lim_{N\to\infty} -\frac{N^2+2N+2}{e^N}+\frac{17}{e^3}=\frac{17}{e^3}.$$
Since the improper integral converges, we conclude that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ converges as well.